# uniroot gives multiple answers to equation with 1 unknown

Tags: r, plyr, uniroot

I want to create a column in a data frame in which each row is the solution to an equation with 1 unknown (`x`). The other variables in the equation are provided in the other columns. In [another Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12028831/r-find-root-of-a-function-for-every-row), @flodel provided a solution, which I have tried to adapt. However, the output data frame omits some observations entirely, and others have "duplicates" with two different solutions to the same equation.

Sample of my data frame:

| Time | id | V1 | V2 | V3 | V4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 199304 | 79330 | 259.721 | 224.5090 | 0.040140442 | 0.08100474 |
| 201004 | 77520 | 5062.200 | 3245.6921 | 0.037812662 | 0.08509553 |
| 196804 | 23018 | 202.897 | 842.6852 | 0.154956206 | 0.12982818 |
| 197804 | 12319 | 181.430 | 341.4415 | 0.052389156 | 0.14196588 |
| 199404 | 18542 | 14807.000 | 16537.0873 | -0.001394388 | 0.08758791 |

Code with the equation I want to solve. I have simplified the equation, but the issue relates to this simple equation too.

```
library(plyr)
library(rootSolve
set.seed(1) 
df <- adply(df, 1, summarize,
      x = uniroot.all(function(x) V1 * ((V4-V3)/(x-V3)) - V2,
                             interval = c(-10,10)))
```

How can I achieve this? If possible, it would be great to do this in an efficient manner, as my actual data frame has >1,000,000 rows

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer by @StefanoBarbi was pointing in the right direction.

Here are the plots of the functions implied by each row of your example data frame, with the solution superimposed as a red vertical line (so that we can see that yes, you're right that there is a root in the interval ...) [code below]

[image: graph showing curves for each row]

The problem is that the algorithm underlying `uniroot()` is only guaranteed to find the root of a function that is **continuous on the interval**. Your functions have discontinuities/singularities. (Even for a continuous function I'm sure that the algorithm could be broken with a function that was sufficiently weird to cause problems with floating-point math ...)

Even a bisection algorithm, which is more robust than Brent's method (the algorithm underlying `uniroot`) since it makes fewer assumptions about continuity of the derivative, could easily fail on this kind of discontinuous function. (It could be made to work for a [function that is discontinuous but monotonic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60804523/bisect-with-discontinuous-monotonous-function-find-root-using-bisection-for-wea), but your example is neither continuous *nor* monotonic ...)

Obviously your real problem is more complex than this (or you would just be using easy analytical solution you referred to); what this means is that you need to find some way to "tame" your function. In this example, if you rearrange the function to avoid dividing by `x-V3` (but without completely solving the equation) then `uniroot()` should work ...

---

```r
f1 <- function(L) with(L, (V1/V2)*(V4-V3) + V3)
f1(df[1,])

png("badfit.png")
par(mfrow = c(2,3), bty = "l", las = 1)
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  with(df[i,],
       curve(V1 * ((V4-V3)/(x-V3)) - V2,
             from = -10, to = 10,
             ylab = "", xlab = ""))
  abline(v=f1(df[i,]), col = 2)
  abline(h=0, col = 4)
}
dev.off()
```